# save textbox as picture in powerpoint_transparancy difficulties

Tags: vba, textbox, transparency, powerpoint

In powerpoint 2010 I want to save an inserted textbox as a picture, which is simply done by right-clicking on the text box and save it. The saved image will **however** include a large amount of transparancy around the text. I am wondering whether this abundance of transparency around the text can be reduced, whithout using photo-editing programs.

I understand that powerpoint is not the right tool to use the beautifuly created texts for other purposes aside from office itself, however this would make things ten times easier for some coworkers of mine.

I hope someone can help me with this, also if it means using VBA or other (complex) codes/languages.

Thnx for your time.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Once you have typed your text in the textbox,

1. Copy the text box, right-click and paste as image
2. Now you have the image of the text box as you will get while saving that textbox as image - - using the save_as_image option
3. Select this image and click on format tab
4. You have an option to crop your image
5. Crop the image and save it as a picture